# How to update the connection string in TableServiceClient

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am using this code

```
TableServiceClient serviceClient = new TableServiceClient("ConnectionString");
```

How can I update the connection string after the TableServiceClient creation?

Comment: can you please share code.

Comment: You shouldn't be updating the connection string after the client creation. If you need to, you should be creating a separate client. You should set you connection string before client creation and then refer it in your client creation code like myconnectionstring = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"     and then TableServiceClient serviceClient = new TableServiceClient(myconnectionstring);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to update the connection string after creating a TableServiceClient instance in the Azure Storage Client Library for .NET.
However, you can create a new TableServiceClient instance with the updated connection string and use that instance instead.

First, make sure you have the Azure SDK for .NET installed in your project.

```
Install-Package Azure.Data.Tables
```

Create a new `TableServiceClient` with the updated connection string. You can specify the connection string when creating the client object and Use the `tableServiceClient` object to interact with your Azure Table Storage

Here is the full code

```cs
    using Azure.Data.Tables;
    using System;
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string currentConnectionString = "InitialConnectionString";
    
            // Create the initial TableServiceClient
            TableServiceClient serviceClient = new TableServiceClient(currentConnectionString);
    
            Console.WriteLine("Initial TableServiceClient created.");
    
            string newConnectionString = "NewConnectionString";
    
            // Create a new TableServiceClient with the updated connection string
            serviceClient = new TableServiceClient(newConnectionString);
    
            Console.WriteLine("New TableServiceClient created with updated connection string.");
    
            string tableName = "YourTableName";
            TableClient tableClient = serviceClient.GetTableClient(tableName);
    
            tableClient.CreateIfNotExists();
    
            Console.WriteLine($"Table '{tableName}' created or already exists with the updated connection string.");
        }
    }
```

**Result**

[image]

[image]